# Why do I not get an error when I import pycharm_lightning

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I am using PyCharm and encountered an error at the line

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
```

because the package `pytorch_lightning` had not been added to my Python interpreter. I used PyCharm to search for the package but it was unable to find it. However, searching the internet, I did come across references to a package called Pytorch Lightning. As a result, I decided to see if PyCharm could locate a package called lightning, and indeed it was able to. After adding this package to the interpreter, the error disappeared.

I have also seen others use the line `import pytorch-lightning as pl`, with a hyphen instead of an underscore.

Are there multiple packages with very similar names in existence or is `pytorch_lightning` the same as `pytorch-lighning` and the same as `lightning`?

Why did my error go away?

Comment: _I have also seen others use the line `import pytorch-lightning`_ No you have not. (At least not successfully.)  The minus sign is not allowed in python variable names.  That name would be interpreted in Python as "import pytorch minus lightning", which is nonsense.  Now perhaps `pytorch-lightning` is the name of the pip package, but pip package names are not always identical to the actual python module name.

Comment: OK. They were code suggestions. Maybe they did not work. Did you notice that even the question tag uses the hyphen rather than the underscore.

Comment: You can see it here several times. https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/15037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is only one [package](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/). it however maintains aliases that can be used interchangeably. the underscore name is preferred.